# How do I design a model that should allow the user to create multiple fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Review` model. My users should be able to write reviews. The view for the `Review#New` should be a form with textfields that the admin creates beforehand.

In other words, my `admin-user` should be able to create multiple instances of a Review model that has different fields, perhaps even of different input types (string, integer, etc.). That way, when a regular user logs in, they see the different form fields that were specified for data collection by the admin user.

Naturally all of that should be stored in the DB for retrieval within the context it was stored (aka for that specific model).

What's the best way to approach this in Rails?

Think of it like a survey form, and a survey form builder.

It would be good if I could do this with Simple-Form, but that's not a requirement.

**Edit 1**

Here is an example of the type of fields that they should be able to add to a review:

[image]

Comment: I think you can check Entity Attribute Value model concepts which applies to any dynamic attributes model situation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model . there are also some trials to provide implementation in rails https://github.com/kostyantyn/hydra_attribute

Answer (score 3):

In my experience a good portion of database design is helped by simply finding the right name for things. In your case I think you are on the right track with thinking about surveys or quizzes.

Check out the [survey](https://github.com/runtimerevolution/survey) gem for ideas. In it the base model is Surveys. Surveys have many Questions. Questions have many Options. Surveys also have many Attempts which are answered surveys. Attempts then have many Answers.

So the corollary for you could be to have Reviews/Evaluations (created by admins) which might have many Criteria/Inquiries (possibly of different types, but we'll get to that in a minute). Then your users would create Responses/Assessments which would belong to a specific Review/Evaluation and have many Answers/Responses.

For different question types (Short Answer, Likert Scale Rating, 1-10, Tag List, etc) you could use polymorphism on the criteria/inquiries.

Hopefully some of these names I've used will help you. Feel free to use a thesaurus for more inspiration.

**EDIT Re:Polymorphism**

*Disclaimer: polymorphism might be overkill depending on your application.*

Sure, I'll expand some. Not exactly. Take a look at the rails guide on [polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) if you haven't already. I think what you would want is

```
class Criterion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :askable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then then I would make a model for each question/criterion type. For example:

```
class ShortAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :criteria, as: :askable
end
class Likert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :criteria, as: :askable
end
```

---

***Side note:** If rails does not properly pluralize criterion to criteria you may need to add the following to your config/initializers/inflections.rb file*

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'criterion', 'criteria'
end
```

---

Comment: Hrmm....that's a great idea. I really like the way you are thinking. Can you expand on the different question types a bit for me please. So an example may be something like `critera_id` and `criteria_type` where `criteria_type` is an enum that correlates to options like `short_answer, likert, tag_list, etc.`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, tried to answer your comment as a comment but it was easier to edit my answer.

Comment: Also (even though its becoming more and more risky to recommend these as they are becoming pretty dated) there are some decent Railscasts that might help you. [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), and [196-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). And since you mentioned you were using Simple Form you might also take a look at [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Answer (score 2):

Scratch solution.

From my experience the easiest solution is to use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html), [json](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) or [jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) type of fields.
This solution play good with Postgresql database.
To achieve this approach you need to add field to your `Review` model.

#### Migrations:

```
# Reviews
def change
  add_column :reviews, :structure, :json
end

# Answers
def change
  add_column :answers, :values, :hstore
end
```

Then you can define model `ReviewStructure` plain ruby class, here you can use [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem to serialize it easely:

```
class ReviewStructure
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :fields, Array[Field]

  class Field
    include Virtus.model

    attribute :name
    attribute :type
  end
end
```

Then define in Review the serialization for structure field:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  serialize :structure, ReviewStructure
end
```

Then you can access structure fields of review with `review.structure.fields`.

#### In view you can use a simple form

```
<% simple_form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <% @review.structure.fields.each do |field|  %>
    <% f.input "values[#{field.name}]", as: field.type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### To access answer results just use:

```
answer.values.each do |field_name, value|
  ...
end
```

#### Note:

As for admin for it's better to handle creation of review structure on client side(using js), and post pure JSON structure via API.

With such approach you will have ability to create quizzes with different types of field.

#### Note:

Please keep in mind that current implementation connect one review to one answer, assuming that the answer model contains all the values of user response.